# Random errors which have nothing to do with my script and pop up in output everytime i make a new game

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

When I make a script and run it, even if it is short and simple like

print("Hello World")

I get this whole load of errors

```
09:00:54.575  Walkspeed Adjuster  -  Server
09:00:55.286  cloud_6691945816.Run Gui.Background.ValueChange:28: attempt to index nil with 'Character'  -  Server
09:00:55.287  Stack Begin  -  Studio
09:00:55.287  Script 'cloud_6691945816.Run Gui.Background.ValueChange', Line 28  -  Studio
09:00:55.287  Stack End  -  Studio
09:00:55.619  Walkspeed Adjuster  -  Client
09:00:56.228  cloud_6691945816.Run Gui.Background.ValueChange:28: attempt to index nil with 'Character'  -  Client
09:00:56.228  Stack Begin  -  Studio
09:00:56.228  Script 'cloud_6691945816.Run Gui.Background.ValueChange', Line 28  -  Studio
09:00:56.228  Stack End  -  Studio
```

Any fixes?

Answer (score -1):

Problem resolved, I had a plug-in virus!